# How can I make a merged observable emit when one of the two observable emits, with the latest value of the other?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am implementing a filter feature in Angular, and I have two observables: the `items$` observable and the `itemsFilter$` observable. The first comes from the store, the second comes from a `BehaviourSubject`.

I'm trying to combine these two observables in order to always apply the filter. Even when the data changes and new *items* are emitted, the filter has to remain applied. Same if the filter changes.

I tried several operators:

- **zip**: only emits when both the observables emit
- **merge**: creates a new observable that emits one single value, from one or the other
- **combineLatest**: is deprecated
- **withLatestFrom(this.itemsFilter$)**: does not emit when `itemsFilter$` emits
- **switchMap(() => this.itemsFilter$)**: does not emit when `itemsFilter$` emits
- **mergeMap(() => this.itemsFilter$)**: does not emit when `itemsFilter$` emits
- **combineLatestAll** requires an observable of observables

In the end, I didn't find a suitable operator for my use-case. What's the standard way of implementing filters with ngrx and rxjs observables?

Comment: fyi, if it's a purely client side filter with no asynchronous aspects (like getting data from a database) and you're using signals you can use a computed signal for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `combineLatest(args: Observable[])` static import from `rxjs` or `combineLatestWith` operator.

Only the `combineLatest(...args: Observable[])` overload is deprecated. The `combineLatest` *operator* is deprecated.

```
combineLatest([items$, itemsFilter$])
```

or

```
items$.pipe(
   combineLatestWith(itemsFilter$),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wish the [Rx documentation](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) was this clear

Comment: I agree. The API was quite wide and they try to narrow it down. It is hard to get oriented in the deprecation land. But I think it's for a good cause. RxJS is a powerful tool but it can get complicated. If it is to stay it needs to become a little simpler.

Comment: Exactly. `combineLatestWith` isn't even mentioned for rxjs. I wonder how someone is supposed to know it :/